npm run build failing for dockerhub image - Remix/run
I'm using DockerHub to build a React Remix app. The container was working until midday yesterday when the build 'miraculously' started failing.
here is a snippet of the Dockerfile:
# base node image
FROM node:20-bullseye-slim as base

ARG NODE_ENV=staging
ARG DOTENV_KEY
ARG COMMIT_SHA
ARG RELEASE_SEMVER

# set for base and all layer that inherit from it
ENV LOG_LEVEL=debug
ENV DEBUG_API=true
ENV NODE_ENV ${NODE_ENV}
ENV DOTENV_KEY ${DOTENV_KEY}
ENV COMMIT_SHA ${COMMIT_SHA}
ENV RELEASE_SEMVER ${RELEASE_SEMVER}

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl tini

# Install all node_modules, including dev dependencies
FROM base as deps

WORKDIR /app

ADD package.json package-lock.json .npmrc ./

RUN npm install --include=dev

# Setup production node_modules
FROM base as production-deps

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules /app/node_modules
ADD package.json package-lock.json .npmrc ./
RUN npm prune --omit=dev

# Build the app
FROM base as build

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules /app/node_modules

ADD . .
ENV NODE_ENV production

RUN npm run build

# Finally, build the production image with minimal footprint
FROM base
ENV NODE_ENV staging
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=production-deps /app/node_modules /app/node_modules

COPY --from=build /app/server-build /app/server-build
COPY --from=build /app/build /app/build
COPY --from=build /app/public /app/public
COPY --from=build /app/package.json /app/package.json
RUN mkdir -p tmp

From what I can deduce, the  build (RUN npm run build) is failing leading to a failure to import the /server-build/index.js file, causing the process to fail and eventually marking the build as a failure.
Here is an excerpt from the error log:
2024-04-09T14:15:09Z #15 [production-deps 4/4] RUN npm prune --omit=dev
2024-04-09T14:15:21Z #15 22.30
2024-04-09T14:15:21Z #15 22.30 up to date, audited 383 packages in 21s
2024-04-09T14:15:21Z #15 22.30
2024-04-09T14:15:21Z #15 22.30 74 packages are looking for funding
2024-04-09T14:15:21Z #15 22.30 run `npm fund` for details
2024-04-09T14:15:21Z #15 22.32
2024-04-09T14:15:21Z #15 22.32 2 moderate severity vulnerabilities
2024-04-09T14:15:21Z #15 22.32
2024-04-09T14:15:21Z #15 22.32 To address all issues, run:
2024-04-09T14:15:21Z #15 22.32 npm audit fix
2024-04-09T14:15:21Z #15 22.32
2024-04-09T14:15:21Z #15 22.32 Run `npm audit` for details.
2024-04-09T14:15:21Z #15 22.32 npm notice
2024-04-09T14:15:21Z #15 22.32 npm notice New patch version of npm available! 10.5.0 -> 10.5.1
2024-04-09T14:15:21Z #15 22.32 npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.5.1>
2024-04-09T14:15:21Z #15 22.32 npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@10.5.1` to update!
2024-04-09T14:15:21Z #15 22.32 npm notice
2024-04-09T14:15:21Z #15 DONE 22.6s
2024-04-09T14:15:21Z
2024-04-09T14:15:21Z #5 [base 1/2] FROM docker.io/library/node:20-bullseye-slim@sha256:123d41e7caa4c85a86e577006c58a224aed782facc063ab8ca6732fc6d883392
2024-04-09T14:15:23Z #5 ...
2024-04-09T14:15:23Z
2024-04-09T14:15:23Z #14 [build 4/4] RUN npm run build
2024-04-09T14:15:23Z #14 24.99 [31m✘ [41;31m[[41;97mERROR[41;31m][0m [1mCould not resolve "./server-build/index.js"[0m
2024-04-09T14:15:23Z #14 24.99
2024-04-09T14:15:23Z #14 24.99 index.js:22:15:
2024-04-09T14:15:23Z #14 24.99 [37m 22 │ await import([32m'./server-build/index.js'[37m)
2024-04-09T14:15:23Z #14 24.99 ╵ [32m~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~[0m
2024-04-09T14:15:23Z #14 24.99
2024-04-09T14:15:23Z #14 24.99
2024-04-09T14:15:24Z #14 25.11 fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
2024-04-09T14:15:24Z #14 25.12
2024-04-09T14:15:24Z #14 25.12 goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
2024-04-09T14:15:24Z #14 25.12 github.com/evanw/esbuild/internal/helpers.(*ThreadSafeWaitGroup).Wait(...)
2024-04-09T14:15:24Z #14 25.12 github.com/evanw/esbuild/internal/helpers/waitgroup.go:36
2024-04-09T14:15:24Z #14 25.12 main.runService.func2()
2024-04-09T14:15:24Z #14 25.12 github.com/evanw/esbuild/cmd/esbuild/service.go:114 +0x59
2024-04-09T14:15:24Z #14 25.12 main.runService(0x1)
2024-04-09T14:15:24Z #14 25.12 github.com/evanw/esbuild/cmd/esbuild/service.go:160 +0x4ed
2024-04-09T14:15:24Z #14 25.12 main.main()
2024-04-09T14:15:24Z #14 25.12 github.com/evanw/esbuild/cmd/esbuild/main.go:232 +0x9e9
2024-04-09T14:15:24Z #14 25.12
2024-04-09T14:15:24Z #14 25.12 goroutine 6 [chan receive]:
2024-04-09T14:15:24Z #14 25.12 main.runService.func1()
2024-04-09T14:15:24Z #14 25.12 github.com/evanw/esbuild/cmd/esbuild/service.go:98 +0x4a
2024-04-09T14:15:24Z #14 25.12 created by main.runService
2024-04-09T14:15:24Z #14 25.12 github.com/evanw/esbuild/cmd/esbuild/service.go:97 +0x1e5
2024-04-09T14:15:24Z #14 25.12
2024-04-09T14:15:24Z #14 25.12 goroutine 7 [chan receive]:
2024-04-09T14:15:24Z #14 25.12 main.(*serviceType).sendRequest(0xc000023bc0, {0x8ddb00, 0xc008904240})
2024-04-09T14:15:24Z #14 25.12 github.com/evanw/esbuild/cmd/esbuild/service.go:192 +0xfa
2024-04-09T14:15:24Z #14 25.12 main.runService.func3()
2024-04-09T14:15:24Z #14 25.12 github.com/evanw/esbuild/cmd/esbuild/service.go:125 +0x39
2024-04-09T14:15:24Z #14 25.12 created by main.runService
2024-04-09T14:15:24Z #14 25.12 github.com/evanw/esbuild/cmd/esbuild/service.go:122 +0x31c
2024-04-09T14:15:24Z #14 25.14 ERROR: "build:remix" exited with 1.
2024-04-09T14:15:24Z #14 25.24 npm notice
2024-04-09T14:15:24Z #14 25.24 npm notice New patch version of npm available! 10.5.0 -> 10.5.1
2024-04-09T14:15:24Z #14 25.24 npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.5.1>
2024-04-09T14:15:24Z #14 25.24 npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@10.5.1` to update!
2024-04-09T14:15:24Z #14 25.24 npm notice
2024-04-09T14:15:24Z #14 DONE 25.4s
2024-04-09T14:15:24Z
2024-04-09T14:15:24Z #5 [base 1/2] FROM docker.io/library/node:20-bullseye-slim@sha256:123d41e7caa4c85a86e577006c58a224aed782facc063ab8ca6732fc6d883392
2024-04-09T14:15:25Z #5 ...
2024-04-09T14:15:25Z
2024-04-09T14:15:25Z #16 [stage-4 2/7] COPY --from=production-deps /app/node_modules /app/node_modules
2024-04-09T14:15:27Z #16 ...
2024-04-09T14:15:27Z
2024-04-09T14:15:27Z #17 [stage-4 3/7] COPY --from=build /app/server-build /app/server-build
2024-04-09T14:15:27Z #17 ERROR: "/app/server-build" not found: not found
2024-04-09T14:15:27Z
2024-04-09T14:15:27Z #16 [stage-4 2/7] COPY --from=production-deps /app/node_modules /app/node_modules
2024-04-09T14:15:28Z #16 CANCELED
2024-04-09T14:15:28Z
2024-04-09T14:15:28Z #5 [base 1/2] FROM docker.io/library/node:20-bullseye-slim@sha256:123d41e7caa4c85a86e577006c58a224aed782facc063ab8ca6732fc6d883392
2024-04-09T14:15:28Z ------
2024-04-09T14:15:28Z > [stage-4 3/7] COPY --from=build /app/server-build /app/server-build:
2024-04-09T14:15:28Z ------
2024-04-09T14:15:28Z ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: "/app/server-build" not found: not found
2024-04-09T14:15:28Z An error occurred. Failed to build Docker image
2024-04-09T14:15:28Z Changing status of deployment to failed

I tried running npm install -g npm@10.5.1 to see if it'd correct the issue to no avail.
I'm not sure what exactly is wrong with the code but I tried getting a Dockerfile from a successfully building environment and it failed too. I merged the code with another branch and the recipient stopped building too.
Before the failure I had an issue where click listeners and other basic functionality stopped working so I had to reset my dev container. Is it possible the container did something on creation? cos the Dockerfile and package.json were untouched so I cannot see why this is happening.
